# Prove that if the element $a\in G$, where $G$ is a group, has order $n$ and its homomorphic image $f(a)$ has order $m$, then $m\mid n$

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

> Let $G$ be a group. If $a\in G$ has order $n$ and its homomorphic image $f(a)$ has order $m$, then $m\mid n$.

So I have a confusion with this question, what does it mean the order of $a$? wouldn't the order be of the group and the homomorphic group of $f(a)$?

besides from that i have tried using Lagrange's theorem but the theorem says that

**The order of the subgroup of $G$ divides the group $G$**
But the homomorphic image of $f(a)$ does not mean that it's a subgroup of $G$ or does it?

I appriciate all help!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An important distinction for you to know is the difference between the order **of a group** and the order **of an element of a group**. It seems like you already understand the former, so the latter:

Let $G$ be a group with identity element $e$, and let $a \in G$. The order of $a$ is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $a^n = e$.

Does knowing this help?

Comment: Thanks so much for answering!
To be honest no, now i'm a bit more confused as to what would the $a^n$ mean, how many times the power of a gives the identity element?, and how could i calculate this order, and wouldn't that imply that to find the order of $f(a)$ i would need to know the rule $f$?.

Comment: @Ramirogenta : $a\cdot a = a^2$.  $a \cdot a \cdot a = a^3$.  "$a^n$" is the product of $n$ copies of $a$.  (... with the convention $a^0$ is the identity.)  If $G$ is finite, by the pigeonhole principle, there are distinct nonnegative integers $m$ and $n$, with $m < n$ such that $a^m = a^n$.  Then multiply through by $(a^m)^{-1}$ to obtain $e = a^{n-m}$, so every element of a finite group has a finite order.  An element of an infinite group has an infinite order if none of its finite powers is the identity.

Comment: @Ramirogenta : You do not need to know the explicit order of $A$, you merely need to know that it *has* an order to give that order a name.  You problem gives you the name of the order of $a$, establishing that its order is $n$.  Then you need to know the (group) homomorphic image of the identity is the identity, so at the very least, $1 = f(1) = f(a^n) = (f(a))^n$.  Then you need to think about what the last term actually promises -- it is not that the order of $f(a)$ is $n$.

Comment: So you are saying that the identity  $1=f(1)=f(a^n)=f(a)^n$, so would that imply that for an arbitrairy $a\in G$ and it has order $n$ then, $a^n=f(a^n)=f(a)^n$ but wouldn't that be $f(a)^n=f(a)^m,n=m$? it seems a bit confusing to me

Comment: @Ramirogenta Sure, $f(a)^n = f(a)^m$. Nothing wrong there. Exercise: pick your favourite finite group and pick an element $a$. Calculate $a^2, a^3, \dots$ until you get the identity. Then, notice that $a^{2n}$ would also be the identity.

Comment: Here's an example from $\mathbb{R}$. $(-1)^2 = (-1)^4$.